# Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.3.2 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.3.2) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

build.gradle(:app)

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
implementation 'com.android.support:design:31.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.41.0'
implementation'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.76.0'
```

}